# In Android How to get the ASCII value of the key which is pressed?

Tags: android

I am trying to get Ascii Value when user press any key from virtual keyboard in android .Any help will be Appreciated.Thanx in Advance.

Comment: what you have tried so far??

Answer (score 1):

it's very simple. Just cast your char as an int.

```
char character = 'a';


int ascii = (int) character;
```

In your case, you need to get the specific Character from the String first and then cast it.

```
char character = name.charAt(0); // This gives the character 'a'
int ascii = (int) character; // ascii is now 97.
```

Though cast is not required explicitly, but its improves readability.

`int ascii = character;` // Even this will do the trick.